# Decrypttion fails on S/MIME enveloped message with OAEP key encryption?

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, bouncycastle, smime

With Java and BouncyCastle I am able to decrypt lots of S/MIME enveloped messages.

But when the key encryption algorithm is `1.2.840.113549.1.1.7` (id-RSAES-OAEP), the decryption fails (stack trace at the end of this question).

The line where it happens:

```
content = messageRecipientInfo.getContent(new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(pc).setProvider("BC"));
```

Formerly I used that line to decrypt:

```
content = messageRecipientInfo.getContent(givenCertRecipient);
```

It's all the same.

Any guess?

- EDIT *

I now tried to ENCRYPT data with OAEP. Therefore I've found code directly inside BouncyCastle in the file cms/test/NewEnvelopedDataTest.java
Even that doesn't work!
The same error:

```
String BC = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;

KeyPair _reciKP = CMSTestUtil.makeKeyPair();
String _reciDN = "CN=Doug, OU=Sales, O=Bouncy Castle, C=AU";
KeyPair _signKP = CMSTestUtil.makeKeyPair();
String _signDN = "O=Bouncy Castle, C=AU";
X509Certificate _reciCertOaep = CMSTestUtil.makeOaepCertificate(_reciKP, _reciDN, _signKP, _signDN);

byte[] data = "WallaWallaWashington".getBytes();

CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator edGen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();

JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter paramsConverter = new JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter();

edGen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(_reciCertOaep).setProvider(BC));

edGen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(ASN1OctetString.getInstance(ASN1OctetString.getInstance(_reciCertOaep.getExtensionValue(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier.getId())).getOctets()).getOctets(), _reciCertOaep.getPublicKey()).setProvider(BC));
```

Here during the last step it crashes: "cannot initialise algorithm parameters: Operation not supported"

```
CMSEnvelopedData edd = edGen.generate(
                new CMSProcessableByteArray(data),
                new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC).setProvider(BC).build());
```

What is the problem? I can't see it...

> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: exception unwrapping key: cannot
>   initialise algorithm parameters: Operation not supported  at
>   org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransRecipient.extractSecretKey(JceKeyTransRecipient.java:169)
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient.getRecipientOperator(JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient.java:26)
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.cms.KeyTransRecipientInformation.getRecipientOperator(KeyTransRecipientInformation.java:48)
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation.getContentStream(RecipientInformation.java:169)
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation.getContent(RecipientInformation.java:150)
>     at CryptoTools.decryptAndVerifyFile(CryptoTools.java:1030)  at
>   FormMain$2.actionPerformed(FormMain.java:403)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot initialise
>   algorithm parameters: Operation not supported     at
>   org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createAlgorithmParameters(OperatorHelper.java:254)
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JceAsymmetricKeyUnwrapper.generateUnwrappedKey(JceAsymmetricKeyUnwrapper.java:100)
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransRecipient.extractSecretKey(JceKeyTransRecipient.java:158)
>     ... 42 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
>     at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.AlgorithmParametersSpi$OAEP.engineInit(AlgorithmParametersSpi.java:83)
>     at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createAlgorithmParameters(OperatorHelper.java:250)
>     ... 44 more

Comment: What's your bouncycastle and java versions?

Comment: Sorry. Java and bouncycastle are up to date: 1.8 and 1.56